# How to get these implementations of a genetic algorithm to repeat?

Tags: python, algorithm, repeat, genetic-algorithm

I'm having trouble figuring out how to have this code repeat. The code is for a beginning genetic algorithm function on which I am working on. I'm an extreme amateur with code, so if it's something stupid, sorry. :)

I think I'm close, I have three variants of code both of which are not quite there, but are relatively close (...maybe...).

Here is **Variation 1** of my code:

```
population_size = int(raw_input('Enter a population size:'))

def make_organism(length):
    from random import randint

length = int(raw_input('Enter an organism length:'))
org = []
for i in range(length):
        var = randint(0, 1)
        org.append(var)

new_org = []
for length in range(population_size):
    var_2 = randint(0, 1)
    new_org.append(var_2)
    print new_org
```

This code returns the correct population but not the correct length.

Ex:

```
Enter a population size: 3
Enter an organism length: 4
[0]
[0, 0]
[0, 0, 0]
```

**Variation 2** of my code:

```
population_size = int(raw_input('Enter a population size:'))

def make_organism(length):
    from random import randint

length = int(raw_input('Enter an organism length:'))
org = []
for i in range(length):
        var = randint(0, 1)
        org.append(var)

new_org = []
for length in range(population_size):
    var = randint(0, 1)
    org.append(length)
    print new_org
```

This code returns the correct population but does not return anything in the brackets. Prints `new_org` as many times as the `population_size` is.

Ex:

```
Enter a population size: 3
Enter an organism length: 4
[]
[]
[]
```

**Variation 3:**

```
population_size = int(raw_input('Enter a population size:'))

def make_organism(length):
    from random import randint

length = int(raw_input('Enter an organism length:'))
org = []
for i in range(length):
        var = randint(0, 1)
        org.append(var)
print org
```

This code will return the correct length with code but not the correct population size.

Ex:

```
Enter a population size: 3
Enter an organism length: 4
[0, 1, 0, 1]
```

`orgs` are organisms represented as empty lists. The code generates a random number pattern of 0's and 1's according to bit length, and should return as many random lists as the user inputs population size.

Comment: I think the formatting on your code as wrong. Add whitespace to make it correct.

Comment: Whitespace is correct, the code works just returns the wrong output. I would have received a syntax error if the whitespace was incorrect.

Comment: Copying what you wrote in your question into a editor and compiling it raises an error at the first randint. I am sure what you have works, you just didn't keep the formatting when you copied to your question. Also, where do you call make_organism?

Comment: What does make_organism do?  I'm no Python guru but to me it looks like it consists of an import statement and nothing else.

Comment: I didn't call make_organism

Comment: Your question is unclear. Exactly what code do you want to repeat? How long or often should this occur (i.e. what determines the number of repetitions or what condition stops them)? Is the code repeated the same each repetition and if not how is it different each time?

Answer (score 0):

If this is the ouput that you were expecting

```
[0, 0, 0, 0]
[1, 1, 1, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 1]
```

then i guess the following simple code should work but it may give repeated lists though

```
import random as rd

pop_size=int(raw_input())
org_len=int(raw_input())

for i in range(pop_size):
    org=[]
    for j in range(org_len):
        org.append(rd.randint(0,1))
    print(org)
```

Hope this Helps :)

Answer (score 0):

You might want to read a little more into python because it seems you don't really know what you are doing. However, what you want to do is quite easy. Here is how I would do it.

```
from random import randint

population_size = int(raw_input('Enter a population size:')) 
length = int(raw_input('Enter an organism length:'))
org = [[randint(0,1) for _ in range(length)] for _ in range(population_size)]
print "\n".join(map(str, org))
```

Going through this line by line

```
from random import randint
```

imports the function randint from library random. You put this in a function which you didn't call, so I am not sure how your code ever worked, but usually this is done at the top of the file.

You know what the next two lines do, because I copied them from you.

```
 org = [[randint(0,1) for _ in range(length)] for _ in range(population_size)]
```

This is a nested list comprehension. The inside part generates a list filled with randomly selected 0s and 1s for the needed length, then the outside part generates that list for each list in the population size. Right now you have something that looks like, for length 4 and population size 3, this:

```
[[1, 0, 0, 1], [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 1, 1]]
```

The last line just formats it to print each organism on a separate line.